# IF Function with multiple VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, concatenation, vlookup

I need help as I need to track changes on my file. I actually have 2 tabs. One is the Old data and the other one is for the new data.

I have a total of 6 columns

Column A B C D and E are for my references

Column F is for Concatenate of Columns A to E

Column G is for Remarks

What I need is for the remarks column to have a remark of "**CHANGED**"if any of the columns in ABCDE changed New data versus the Old data

"**No Changed**" if the data in Old data tab and New tab data matched

"**New**" if the data in New data tab cannot be found in Old data tab

Here's what I have done so far:

*CONCATENATE* is the column name in the New data tab

```
=IF(VLOOKUP([@CONCATENATE],'Old data'!F:F,1,0)=[@CONCATENATE], "NO CHANGE", "CHANGED")
```

Whenever I make changes, N/A is showing as the result

The progress so far is now okay but just need the New remarks for the newly added data.

If the data is neither changed or no changed, meaning not existing in either old tab or new tab, it should return a New value

```
=ifna(if(iserror(vlookup([@concatenate],'Old data'!G:G,1,0)),"Changed","No Changed"),"NEW")
```

Comment: `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP([@CONCATENATE],'Old data'!G:G,1,0)),"CHANGED","NO CHANGE")`

Comment: ^^^FYI, `VLOOKUP` returns `#N/A` is the looked for value is not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments VLOOKUP returns an error if the value is not found.  And if the criteria in an IF returns an error it will error.

So use ISERROR() to return TRUE/FALSE to the IF:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP([@CONCATENATE],'Old data'!G:G,1,0)),"CHANGED","NO CHANGE")
```

Another method that may be a little quicker is to use MATCH:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH([@CONCATENATE],'Old data'!G:G,0)),"CHANGED","NO CHANGE")
```

This is my preferred method.

Comment: Sir, I was going to comment that sir please post as an answer. Sir also, instead of `ISERROR()` can we use `ISNUMBER()` as well.

Comment: Hi @scott, that works for changed and no changed. But for the data not existing in Old data, there should be a remarks as "New"

Comment: You will need to add test data, as I do not understand.

Comment: =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP([@CONCATENATE],'Old data'!G:G,1,0)),"CHANGED","NO CHANGE") is working already But if a data in New tab is not existing or cannot be found in Old data, The remark should be NEW instead of CHANGED or NO CHANGED. Overall, there should be a total of 3 remarks.

Comment: Again.  I will need to see some test data and expected output, words are not getting the point across.  At this point ask a new question and include test data in markup table format so we can copy paste and expected output.

Comment: =ifna(if(iserror(vlookup([@concatenate],'Old data'!G:G,1,0)),"Changed","No Changed"),"NEW")

Comment: i don't know how to make it a markup comment

Comment: You will need to edit the post to include it there.  comments are not for that sort of thing. @NorilynAnnPontillas

Comment: I have edited the remarks. Like if the value is neither changed or no changed, the return value should be new

Comment: @NorilynAnnPontillas please include test data.  words are not sufficient for us to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Building off what the others here have answered, it sounds like it should be something like:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH([@Concatenate],'Old data'!F:F,0)),"NEW", IF([@Concatenate]=INDEX('Old data'!F:F,ROW([@Concatenate])),"NO CHANGE", "CHANGED"))
```

Its a bit ambiguous to determine the exact difference between New and Changed in your question. I have assumed that "CHANGED" means that the corresponding row in new data is different "Old data", but the value in new data can be found elsewhere in column F in old data.

On the other hand, new would be if the value has changed between old and new data but the new value cannot be found within the entirity of column F of the Old data sheet...

Comment: thank you for the comment. as for the different between new and changed

New is like data is can be found in only one tab. Either old tab or new tab. It's like it's not existing in either of the two tabs

Changed is like the data are both existing in the two tabs but there is a revision made.

Comment: sorry its still not clear to me - the formula above isn't any closer to what you are after?

Comment: i tried the formula you commented but all of the remarks are showing New. The comment of Scott is working already but just need to add new remarks for those data that are newly added on the file.

Comment: Sorry, and thats not just because its looking at column F and not G? I noticed a difference in the above formulas vs mine - its hard to see without example data as suggested by Scott